# firebase.json postdeploy authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "postdeploy": [
      "firebase list",
      "firebase database:set /config deploy/database/config.json -y"
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  }
}
```

And `database.rules.json`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, on CI the postdeploy step fails:

```
Running command: firebase list
┌──────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ Name                                 │ Project ID / Instance      │ Permissions │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ My App Name (current)                │ my-app-name                │ Editor      │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘

Running command: firebase database:set /config
deploy/database/config.json -y Error: An unexpected error has
occurred. Error: functions postdeploy error: Command terminated with
non-zero exit code2
```

The Firebase command is clearly being run as `Editor`.

I'm also able to run `firebase database:set /config deploy/database/config.json -y` locally.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `"source": "functions"` setting doesn't apply to the location of my scripts. I changed the script location from

```
firebase database:set /config deploy/database/config.json -y
```

to

```
firebase database:set /config functions/deploy/database/config.json -y
```

...and now it works:

```
Running command: firebase database:set /config functions/deploy/database/config.json -y
✔  Data persisted successfully
```

In conclusion, error code `2` is if the `firebase database:set` command can't find the JSON input file.